# Not able to get file name from same file path in two different activities

Tags: java, android, file, listview

I'm trying to create a file that acts as a folder for other files, and display the list of all those files in a listView. I start in the listView activity, then use an intent to go to the "add file" activity. The user names the file and I get the name by putting the EditText stuff into a String fileBeingAddedTitle. The code I'm using to make the files is

```
File folderFile = getApplicationContext().getDir("folder_file",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File fileBeingAdded = new File(folderFile.getPath(), fileBeingAddedTitle);
```

After this an intent is started to head back to the listActivity. There I hoped I could just use ".getDir" to find the 'folder file', then just use .list() to get the names on an array. Then I was going to transfer from that array to an arrayList so that I could use an arrayAdapter to get the content on the listView.

```
File folderFile = getApplicationContext().getDir("folder_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String[] fileListViewContentArray = folderFile.list();
for(int i=0; i<fileListViewContentArray.length-1; i++){

    fileListViewContentArrayList.add(fileListViewContentArray[i]);

}
```

From here I use an arrayAdapter and I've used dummy content already to make sure that part works (which it does). My problem is that the list isn't being displayed, and I'm 90% sure it has to do with the files, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The paths are exactly the same so I have no idea whats wrong. Pls help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you actually writing anything to the files, or are you just creating `File` objects?

Comment: @MikeM. The Idea is to make a file that creates Files that will eventually hold strings like descriptions and dates and whatnot. So in this process its just creating File objects. I'm trying to get the names of these file objects.

Comment: Yeah, if you're just creating Java `File` objects, and not writing anything to them, or somehow otherwise forcing their creation on disk, they won't be physically created. Try using the `File#createNewFile()` method for each, and see if that was your problem.

Comment: Would this need to be done in a try/catch format? Also would I be applying    createNewFile() method on the Folder or the file being added?

Comment: Yes, `createNewFile()` throws `IOException`, which you need to `catch`. The `getDir()` method will take care of creating the directory, so you just need to call `createNewFile()` on the actual file `File`s.

Comment: I added fileBeingAdded.createNewFile(); to a try and catch the IOException, but when I hover over the method it gives me a message that it's being ignored.

Comment: @MikeM. I added another createNewFile to the folder itself and everythings is working now! I can't describe how thankful I am. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. What was the "ignored" thing? That is, what was the exact message? Just curious. It sounds like it was some warning from your IDE that you could probably ignore. It doesn't sound like a compilation error.

Comment: The exact text is "Result of File.createNewFile() is ignored..." but it hasn't affected the code in anyways that I've noticed yet so I don't think I'll worry too much about it.

Comment: The `createNewFile()` method returns a `boolean` indicating whether it created the file. That warning is just telling you that you're not using the return value. You can disregard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Comments above to the question you'll find the solution Mike M. provided me. Adding this just after creating the file in the first block of code in my question

```
File folderFile = getApplicationContext.getDir("folder_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File fileBeingAdded = new File(folderFile.getPath(), fileBeingAddedTitle);
try{
    folderFile.createNewFile();
    fileBeingAdded.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This physically instantiated the file (for me anyways) and the list works great now. Thanks again to Mike M.